# How can I implement Android 4.0 designed (Holo) like text fields?

Tags: android, textfield

I do have the latest Android API and a ICS emulator running, but I can't find text fields that look like:

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/text-fields.html

Is there a way to get those new text fields instead of the older text fields "boxes"?

Comment: Do you inherit from a specific theme? You need to inherit from the Holo theme instead of the default to get the Holo look.

Comment: Yes I do have: `<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
</resources>` in /res/values-v11/styles.xml and applied that theme in my Android Manifest file:     `<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" > ...` but is still in old design on ICS emulator.

Comment: I needed platform specific value folders as described here: /res/values/ AND /res/values-v11/
( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme ). Now it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed platform specific value folders as described here:

/res/values/ AND /res/values-v11/

[developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme)

Now it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the Target SDK field set to in the AndroidManifest.xml file? To get the appropriate holo-styled items, this needs to be at 11 or above (I'd recommend 15, the lastest API level). If it's between 11 and 13 (Honeycomb) I think you also have to set the hardware accelerated option to "true".

Note that using your app on a device below API level 11 (Gingerbread or below) won't have these new styles and will just resort to the old styles (the ones you are currently seeing).

Comment: Thanks, but I've set `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. But the text fields are still in old boxes design on my ICS emulator...?!

Comment: that's really odd. Try cleaning your project if dmon's comment doesn't work.